# Inserting an html page into a block in drupal 7

Tags: html, drupal-7

I have an HTML file I wish to insert into a block in `Drupal-7`. My problem is that this file accesses JavaScript scripts and images on a folder outside of drupal, how can I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, drupal html pages can access external javascript and image files with no problems. If you turn the URLs in the HTML document into absolute paths, it should just work. Make sure you select "full HTML" as the format for the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly that'll be going through thousands of lines of code, isn't there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you have to do in the thousands of lines of code? Are you talking about changing the paths, or is there something else? If it's just changing to absolute paths, you should be able to do that with a quick find-and-replace in a text editor.

Comment: Well, I have the images divided into twelve different files and about 15 different javascript scripts...

Comment: How were you telling the page where the images were before? Even if they were relative links, you must have been specifying what folder they were in.